# Why changing the reference of a pointer doesn't change it's original value?

Tags: c++, pointers

I feel I miss some key concepts about references and pointers; I have the code like this

```
#include "stdio.h"
struct bar {};
class foo {
  public:
    foo(){
      barPtr = new bar();
    };
    bar* barPtr;

    bar*& getBarPtr() {
      return barPtr;
    };

};

int main() {
  foo fObject;
  bar* b = nullptr;

  b = fObject.getBarPtr();
  printf("B before updates %p\n", b);
  printf("barPtr before b updates %p\n", fObject.barPtr);

  b = new bar();
  printf("B after updates %p\n", b);
  printf("barPtr after b updates %p\n", fObject.barPtr);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
b before updates 0x55db559ace70
barPtr before b updates 0x55db559ace70
b after updates 0x55db559ad2a0
barPtr after b updates 0x55db559ace70
```

What I want to achieve is changing what `barPtr` points to by using `b`, so I make `getBarPtr` function returns the reference of `barPtr`. What I don't understand is why changing `b` doesn't change `barPtr`.

Comment: *"What I want to achieve is changing what barPtr points to by using b"* - then `b` needs to be either a reference-to-pointer or a pointer-to-pointer with additional dereferencing. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your definition of `b` to:

```
bar*& b = fObject.getBarPtr();
```

What you are currently doing is copying the pointer of `fObject` into `b`: they are two independent objects. They have the same value (the address that points to the `bar` object you created in `foo`'s constructor), but they are not related to each other. So if you assign a new value to `b`, you will overwrite it, without `fObject`'s `barPtr` changing.

Answer (score 0):

`b` and `barPtr` are two pointers to the same object in memory. Once you assign a new value to `b`, it just means it will point to a different object - as you've seen, it won't affer `barPtr`.

If you had modified the object itself (e.g., doing something like `barPtr->modifyMyData()`), you would have seen the modified value from both pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think by changing the pointer-variable b, the class instance will be changed?
You won't change it this way.

You have allocated two different pointer variables, one in the class foo and one outside: b;

You could use a pointer to pointer. And return the reference to the class's pointer and then change the content of this reference.